# How to concatenate strings in a header?

Tags: c++, header

I want to define a bunch of constants in a dedicated header file.

Since some prefixes occur quite frequently, I want to define them once and then add them whenever it's needed.

My question is:

How can I concatenate a prefix with another string without space?

Example:

```
#define PREFIX "pre_"
#define KEYWORD "keyword"
#define BOTH PREFIX+KEYWORD
```

Desired result for BOTH: pre_keyword

obviously the + in

```
BOTH PREFIX+KEYWORD
```

will not work.
So how can these tokens be concatenated?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Comment: `##` does the concatenation.

Comment: @AlokSave not in this case.

Comment: @fritzone That's for tokens, but the question discusses C-strings.

Comment: Can you clear up the requirements. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to define string constants, which _can_ be available for all classes. It seems convenient to have a dedicated (header) file, because at some point I might decide to write that file (and thus the string constants) with another program. These strings will be used as keys for a map<string, double>

Comment: so, what speaks against using macros?

Answer (score 7):

Just

```
#define BOTH PREFIX KEYWORD
```

would do it.

Adjacent literals are automatically concatenated, so

```
"pre_" "keyword"
```

would become

```
"pre_keyword"
```

Comment: I'm using these constants as keys in a map<string, double>. It works fine for plain constants but not for concatenated strings!

Comment: @bogus then you're doing it wrong. You shouldn't even be using a macro for that, and macros are expanded before the program runs, so even if you do use macros, you're just obfuscating the code.

Comment: Ok, which approach would you suggest? Define constants in a cpp as regular strings?

Comment: @bogus: You could (and probably should) replace those `#define` with constant variables, preferably encapsulated in a namespace of a class to avoid polluting the global namespace. These variables could be either `char const * const` or `std::string const`, the latter allowing you to concatenate them in a simpler way (with `operator+`).

Comment: @bogus definitely use `std::string` as Luc suggested.

Comment: ACtually, in this case, macros are probably the best solution.  They're the only solution which will allow compile time concatenation.  You don't need (or want) any variables for this.  (And `std::string` won't work at all.)

Comment: @JamesKanze well, it depends on whether he actually has the strings at compile-time.

Comment: @LucianGrigore: "You shouldn't even be using a macro for that" - probably true but it's useful to explain pros/cons, but "macros are expanded before the program runs, so even if you do use macros, you're just obfuscating the code." how do they obfuscate more than using a constant? Either way you see the symbolic name rather than value in the source....  @LucTouraille: "These variables could be either `char const * const` or `std::string const`" - `const char []` more accurately expresses the minimal memory requirements than `char const* const`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: "it depends on whether he actually has the strings at compile-time" the question strongly suggests that.

Comment: @TonyD "You shouldn't even be using a macro for that" is almost certainly false; as the problem is presented, a macro is the only solution which is appropriate.

Comment: @JamesKanze from his comment "It works fine for plain constants but not for concatenated strings" I gethered the strings aren't known at compile-time - because they would be constants. I might be wrong, and I asked for clarifications to the question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I interpreted that to refer to the `+`.  If the constants are e.g. integral constants, the `+` works.  If they're string literals, it doesn't.  I don't think the question makes sense otherwise, since if you're e.g. reading values from a file, you're clearly using `std::string` and its operators.

Comment: @JamesKanze: "almost certainly false" - it may not be necessary to have a compile-time-constant value, particularly when the question says it'll be used as a key for a map.  I say "probably true" because macros are evil etc.; I say there are pros/cons which should have been listed because of the compile-time concatenation aspect.

Comment: Both the prefix and the keyword are defined in the header and thus available at compile time. What I want is the result (the concatenation) to be available at compile time

Comment: @TonyD He explicitly asked for concatenation of tokens---compile time, thus.  Obviously, the map will use `std::string` as a key, but those strings will be initialized by string literals, which implies the use of a macro.

Comment: @JamesKanze: he may have asked for it, but given the evils of macros and that the stated use doesn't require a compile-time constant, it's reasonable to recommend against it when explaining the pros/cons. My complaint re this answer is that it didn't try to list the pros and cons, it simply said macros shouldn't be used. Everything where it's the best compromise.  Whether we state a preference for or against is less important than illustrating the reasons for others to make the assessment.

Comment: @TonyD Would the fact that it cannot be done without macros be a reasonable pro?

Comment: @JamesKanze: we're going around in circles - concatenating strings for use as a map key can be done at runtime... maps aren't initialised at compile time, unless something dramatic changed with C++11 that I haven't got my head around (not enough time to play with it, and haven't migrated at work).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to macros, this is a short explanation of what's going on and how it can be improved.

```
#define PREFIX "pre_"
#define KEYWORD "keyword"
```

defines two macros which will be replaced by their definition during pre-processing.

```
#define BOTH PREFIX+KEYWORD
```

will then be replaced by

```
"pre_"+"keyword"
```

resulting in pointer addition, clearly not what you want. As in C and C++ we can split up C-strings by just writing the parts next to each other without any operator (they will be treated as *one* C-string literal, not a concatenation of *two* C-strings):

```
"pre_" "keyword"
```

So you want the macro to be

```
#define BOTH PREFIX KEYWORD
```

If such prefixes will be used quite often in your program, I rather recommend the following method:

```
#define PRE(x) "pre_" x
```

and "invoke" the macro with

```
PRE("keyword")
```

which will expand to `"pre_" "keyword"`.

Now if `"keyword"` will always be a compile-time C-string which can be written as a *token* (no special characters), you can even make it work without the quotes:

```
#define PRE(x) "pre_" #x
```

The `#x` will "convert" the token `x` into a C-string literal. Then, you can write the following:

```
PRE(keyword)
```

Note that this is done by the pre-processor, so `keyword` can even be a C/C++ keyword and it will still be valid, like `PRE(if)`.

For completeness: If you want the result to be still a token, you can perform token concatenation using the pre-processor operator `##`:

```
#define PRE(x) pre_ ## x
```

Then, `PRE(keyword)` will expand to `pre_keyword`.

Comment: +/-0 ;-).  Good explanation of concatenation, but "I rather recommend the following" is dubious and the PRE(keyword) is dangerously counterintuitive... someone saying PRE(x) may expect it to use local variable "x" somehow.

Comment: `PRE(x)` should always be read as a macro. You always have the problem that by only looking at the macro usage code you don't know what's going on. But when writing all macros in upper case you SHOUT at the code reader: `I_AM_DANGEROUS_SO_HAVE_A_LOOK_WHAT_I_AM_DOING` ;) **Never** write `pre(x)` though, as in this case I'd fully agree with you. For example, if you write a parser and have token like `if`, `else` etc. you want to store them in `parser_token_if`, etc., so you could write `TOK(if)` expanding to `parser_token_if`. And of course, keep the macro definition as local as possible.

Comment: I don't particularly like the use of a function style macro here.  I don't see any problem with the way he originally wanted to do it.

Comment: @JamesKanze If he wants to prefix a couple of things, it's good to write one "prefixer". I consider it good style, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Since it is only one prefix (so far at least), the PRE(x) doesn't really mess up my code. It seems to be a well working and conveniently legible solution.